# Icon on angular

Tags: angular, icons

I'm working on the framework angular which has `material-icon` implemented, the **problem is that this code** :

```
export class MenuService {

    public items: MenuItem[];

    constructor(private authService: AuthService) {
        this.items = [
            { 
              id: 'pageHome', 
              label: 'Menu principal', 
              icon: 'home', 
              routerLink: ['/'] 
            },
            { 
              id: 'pageListeMateriel', 
              label: 'Liste des materiels', 
              icon: 'square_foot', routerLink: ['/liste_materiel'] 
            },
            { 
              id: 'deconnexion', 
              label: 'Se déconnecter', 
              icon: 'reply', 
              command: (event) => { this.authService.logout(); }
            } 
        ];
    }
}
```

In `menu.service.ts` doesn't return the icon that I am looking for, it's returning nothing, but the other icon like drive_eta for example return the good one. Can any one help me ?

Comment: Please provide more code.

Comment: More code is added

Comment: <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
      rel="stylesheet"> Did you add this in your index.html?